# Drop all connection to MS Access Database using ADO.NET

Tags: ms-access, ado.net

I am trying to compact an Access Database but it is failing because a connection to the database is still open. How can I drop all connections to the database programmatically?

Comment: You can't, unless you're creating them.

Comment: Is the file on a Windows Server?

Comment: @Jeff : No. I am actually using access as a  desktop database installed with a .NET winform application. I was trying to compact the database but it won't let me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer you cant, long answer you can!

There is no built in way of doing this like on a SQL server however with a bit of preplanning you can set things up to kick users out of a database. See this article on some methods you can use

http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/download3.asp?SampleName=LogUsersOff.mdb

Comment: +1, that's the way to go. I would just add this: sample in the link provides a linked table called 'Settings' with only one Yes/No field called 'Logoff'. I prefer to have a [Condition] field where I could simply type True or False, but where I could also type an boolean expression lke 'User = "Kevin"' in order to selectively throw out specific users. The trick is to use Evaluate([Condition]).

Answer (score -1):

The access program may be open or the process is still running.  Check out these two links on how to kill processes.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cskillapp.aspx

http://www.csharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/ProcessKillCSharp04302008060422AM/ProcessKillCSharp.aspx

Comment: Very, very dangerous recommendation. You're recommending a forced shutdown, which can corrupt data if there's a pending write. -1